# Increment an integer variable in a loop

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have "i" that is an integer variable and I would like to do a loop that increments the "i" from 40000 to 90000 adding 1000 each time. Each Result will appear in a ComboBox.

Example: 40000 - 41000 - 42000 - 43000 - ... - 88000 - 89000 - 90000

My code is the following:

```
var i:integer;
begin
 for i:= 40000 to 90000 do
  begin
   ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i), nil); //until here the code works
   Inc(i, 1000);                         
  end;
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Although I and many know the nature of what type of error you get, you should *always* tell us what the error message is.

Comment: Please, read an error message entirely and consult (F1) the documentation for resolution. It states what you cannot modify the counter of `for` loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot alter the for loop variable inside the loop.

What you want is this:

```
for i := 0 to 50 do
  ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(40000 + 1000 * i), nil)
```

But! This is rather inefficient. You should consider

```
ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
for i := 0 to 50 do
  ComboBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(40000 + 1000 * i));
ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
```

Comment: Even though this does the job, I think this type of loop hides the logic for the reader. Usually I try to implement this loop as a while loop as shown by @KenWhite, but going one step further is to implement a library taking care of a for..step loop. See my answer, the second one would be a keeper in my utilities.

Comment: @LURD: I was just about to add the `while` option to my answer, but Ken beat me to it. Anyhow, I think it depends on the 'underlying' logic. Sometimes the `for` loop might be the most natural one. (One might get the feeling that the `while` appraoch tries to simulate something that the programmer should really prove at design time.)

Answer (score 12):

The alternative to @AndreasRejbrand's solution is a `while` loop:

```
i := 40000;
while i <= 90000 do
begin
  ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i), nil);
  Inc(i, 1000);
end;
```

or `repeat':

```
i := 40000;
repeat
  ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i), nil);
  Inc(i, 1000);
until i > 90000;
```

Comment: +1 but I think using `<= 90000` is a bit less confusing for some people.

Comment: @Jerry: I didn't suggest using it instead; I just offered an alternative.  I upvoted Andreas' answer. :-)

Comment: I meant I would have used `<= 90000` rather than `< 90001` which does the same thing and doesn't necessarily matter, other than readability

Comment: @Jerry: Yep, you're right. That would be more readable. Edited to fix. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: Not really connected to this answer, but why is everyone using 'AddItem' when the second parameter is always nil? Why not use 'add' - ComboBox1.Add (IntToStr(i)); ?

Comment: @No'am Maybe it's because the original poster use AddItem

Answer (score 3):

The compiler prohibits altering the loop variable.

There is a way to include support for a `for..step` loop.
You must have a Delphi version that supports generics (Delphi-2009+).

Just make this declaration in a utility unit:

```
Type
  ForLoop = record
    class procedure Step( Start,Stop,AStep : Integer; 
                          ALoop : TProc<Integer>); static;
  end;

class procedure ForLoop.Step(Start,Stop,AStep : Integer; ALoop: TProc<Integer>);
begin
  while (start <= stop) do
  begin
    ALoop(start);
    Inc(Start,AStep);
  end;
end;
```

---

And use it like this:

```
ForLoop.Step( 40000,90000,1000,
  procedure ( i : Integer)
  begin
    ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i), nil);
  end
);
```

---

In Delphi-2005, methods on records were added plus the `for in` enumeration.

Knowing this, it is possible to implement another for loop with a step functionality.

```
type
  Range = record
  private
    FCurrent,FStop,FStep : Integer;
  public
    constructor Step( Start,Stop,AnIncrement : Integer);
    function GetCurrent : integer; inline;
    function MoveNext : boolean; inline;
    function GetEnumerator : Range; // Return Self as enumerator
    property Current : integer read GetCurrent;
  end;

function Range.GetCurrent: integer;
begin
  Result := FCurrent;
end;

function Range.GetEnumerator: Range;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;

function Range.MoveNext: boolean;
begin
  Inc(FCurrent,FStep);
  Result := (FCurrent <= FStop);
end;

constructor Range.Step(Start,Stop,AnIncrement: Integer); 
begin
  Self.FCurrent := Start-AnIncrement;
  Self.FStop := Stop;
  Self.FStep := AnIncrement;
end;
```

And now you can write :

```
for i in Range.Step(40000,90000,1000) do
  ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i), nil);
```

To dig into the inner workings of this example, see [`more-fun-with-enumerators`](http://hallvards.blogspot.se/2007/10/more-fun-with-enumerators.html).

---

It is easy to implement a `.StepReverse` version of the two examples above, and I will leave that as an exercise to the interested reader.

Answer (score 0):

We can also make a loop from 40 to 90 and multiply the index with 1000

```
var i: integer;
begin
    for i:= 40 to 90 do
    begin
        ComboBox1.AddItem(IntToStr(i*1000), nil);     
    end;                 
end;
```